# How to use AJAX POST request to add elements in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to link my API with a table where I upload the content of API in. After that, I want to customize my table in such way that:

1. I can add new elements (in JSON data) in the table
2. I can see all of the added elements without leaving my page
3. The content of the elements gets posted in the API (with an AJAX POST request)

I have NO idea how to write this code. I'm still a beginner and I have no insight in JQuery of AJAX of other functions.
Can someone please help me??

So far, this is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1> Inventory List </h1>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$.getJSON('http://wt.ops.few.uva.nl/api/-----',
function (json) {
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].category + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].name + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].amount + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].location + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].date + "</td>");
        $('#table').append(tr);
    }
    });
});

</script>

<table id= "table">
  <tr>
    <th> Name of product</th>
    <th> Category</th>
<th> Amount</th>
<th> Location</th>
<th> Date</th>
  </tr>
```

```
<form action="http://wt.ops.few.uva.nl/api/-----" method= "post">

<strong> Add new product </strong> <br>
    <label> Name of Product:</label> <input type="text" name="name" /><br/>

    <label> Category:</label> 
    <input list="category" name="category"/>
            <datalist id="category">
            <option value="Stationery">
            <option value="Home and Living">
            <option value="Foods and Drinks">
            <option value="Clothing and Shoes">
            <option value="Technology">
            </datalist>
    <label>Amount:</label> <input type="text" name= "amount"/><br/>

    <label>Location: </label><input type="text" name="location"/><br/>

    <label> Date:</label> <input type="text" name="date" /><br/>

    <input type= "submit" value="Submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sticking with what you have, add a form and try to submit that to your API as step one.

Comment: The content of my form submits to my API, but it loads the whole page whereas I want it to add the new content to the table without leaving my page..

Comment: Here is a codepen of your code, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZXNrX . On your server, you need a way to handle an incoming post request.  On the server, you need an endpoint that accepts a http post, with a JSON body (preferably) and adds that data to the JSON on the server.  What language is on the server?

Comment: Thank you very much! How can I look up the language of the server? I guess it's English-UK?

Comment: is someone here to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this codepen, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZXNrX.  You just do a post request using Jquery to the URL you gave and it will handle adding it to the array of objects.  Click the button, it will pop up with the response from the Post request.  Then refresh the page to see your item added to the bottom of the list.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1> Inventory List </h1>
  <button>Add Pears</button>
<script>




$(document).ready(function () {
   var data = '{"category": "Fruit", "name": "Pear", "amount": 12, "location": "Amsterdam", "date": "2014-10-05", "id": 20530}'

  $("button").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
    $.post("http://wt.ops.few.vu.nl/api/79fe2e95", data, function(result){
                 alert("Response from request: " + JSON.stringify(result));
          });
    });



$.getJSON('http://wt.ops.few.vu.nl/api/79fe2e95',
function (json) {
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].category + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].name + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].amount + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].location + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].date + "</td>");
        $('#table').append(tr);
    }
});
});

</script>

<table id= "table">
  <tr>
<th> Name of product</th>
<th> Category</th>
<th> Amount</th>
<th> Location</th>
<th> Date</th>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! I have one question left: where can I put a PreventDefault function to prevent the page from leaving?

Comment: I updated my answer above.  Pass a variable into the click function, you can call it anything you want.  That variable passed in is the event.  Most people call it e or event.  Then just call the event's method, preventDefault().